# Hide username discovery

Tags: wp-admin, users, security

How do I stop my usernames being leaked? To explain I tested my WordPress site on http://wprecon.com, and found that my admin username (that I have changed) was able to be discovered.

> User Enumeration is possible by querying the author parameter and cycling through user id's /?author=1

Changing the admin user is recommended in all the security guides but it seems it is not difficult to find the new user.

Comment: Make sure your "nice name" in your profile is different to your login - this is the field used for author archive permalinks.

Comment: Another security tip is to make sure the first user in the database (i.e. user ID of 1) is not the administrator.  Personally I wouldn't lose sleep over username discovery, far more important to ensure you have strong passwords (or consider restricting access to the admin area by IP address, using 2-factor auth etc.)